# Create a virtual machine with a custom image, which cannot be accessed through load balancing

Tags: load-balancing, image

I created a virtual machine instance through a custom image, added it to an unmanaged instance group, and associated the instance group with the network load balancer, but I could not access the MySQL service on the virtual machine through the external IP address of the load balancer.

Comment: are you sure, MySQL daemon is listening to your IP address?
by default, it only listens on 127.0.0.1(localhost IP). you can check via the following command. "netstat -ntlp"

Comment: It's hard to say exactly whats wrong on this type of questions, as they are very vague. But to start, what load balancer and hypervisor are you using? Have you check that the MySQL service works without the load balancer? What have you tried already and what works/doesn't work etc.